# C# Get DataRow of DataTable Without Using ForEach

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

If my `DataTable` is `NOT NULL`, it will only have `1` row,.

How can I point to the `DataRow` directly instead of looping through the `DataTable` with my current `foreach`?

**Sample:**

```
if (matchedRecordsDT != null)
{
    foreach (DataRow matchedRecordsDR in matchedRecordsDT .Rows)
    {
        string matchedRecordTitle = matchedRecordsDR["Title"].ToString();
    }
{
```

Comment: Did you try `Rows[0]`?

Comment: `matchedRecordsDT.Rows[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the first record from the Rows and then get the Title from that all in one go.

```
var matchedRecordTitle = matchedRecordsDT.Rows.First()["Title"].ToString();
```